# For Loop with Dictionary / List Not Counting

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, for-loop

My inner most nested for loop is not counting correctly. It turns into an infinite loop and I'm not seeing why. Does it have something to do with

```
studentScores.Add(intScore);
```

being inside the nested for loop?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string studentCount = string.Empty;
        string examCount = string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of students you will enter.");
        studentCount = Console.ReadLine();
        int totalStudents = Convert.ToInt32(studentCount);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of exams to be entered for each student.");
        examCount = Console.ReadLine();
        int totalExams = Convert.ToInt32(examCount);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        Dictionary<int, List<int>> studentMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        List<int> studentScores = new List<int>();

        for (int students = 0; students < totalStudents; students++)
        {
            for (int scores = 0; scores < totalExams; scores++)
            {
                string score = string.Empty;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter exam");
                score = Console.ReadLine();
                int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(score);
                studentScores.Add(intScore);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it, your loop will end after you supply N values.  N being totalStudents * totalExams

Comment: Did you mean to add `studentScores` to `studentMap` (and then assign a new `List` to `studentScores`) inside your outer loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code snippet. See [here for full working code](https://ideone.com/ZrRf2M):

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> studentMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

for (int students = 0; students < totalStudents; students++)
{
    //Create List<int> here for each student
    List<int> studentScores = new List<int>(); 
    for (int scores = 0; scores < totalExams; scores++)
    {
       //Read and save scores of student in each subject
        string score = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter exam");
        score = Console.ReadLine();
        int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(score);
        studentScores.Add(intScore);
    }

    //Add this in dictonary. Key as the `index` and 
    //value as the scores saved in `studentScores`
    studentMap.Add(students, studentScores);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> studentScores = new List<int>();

for (int students = 0; students < totalStudents; students++)
{
    for (int scores = 0; scores < totalExams; scores++)
    {
        string score = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter exam");
        score = Console.ReadLine();
        int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(score);
        studentScores.Add(intScore);
    }
}
```

should likely be:

```
for (int students = 0; students < totalStudents; students++)
{
    List<int> studentScores = new List<int>();
    for (int scores = 0; scores < totalExams; scores++)
    {
        string score = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter exam");
        score = Console.ReadLine();
        int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(score);
        studentScores.Add(intScore);
    }
    studentMap[students] = studentScores;
}
```

This will mean each entry in the `Dictionary` will have a subset of the `studentScores` data. This is different to your existing code, which lumps all of the `studentScores` data in a single `List`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the clarifications that you provided in the comment, you should try something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> studentMap = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
for (int student = 0; student < totalStudents; student++)
{
    studentMap.Add(student, new List<int>());
    for (int scores = 0; scores < totalExams; scores++)
    {
        string score = string.Empty;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter exam");
        score = Console.ReadLine();
        int intScore = Convert.ToInt32(score);
        studentMap[student].Add(intScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the repeated `studentMap[student]` hash lookups?

Comment: @mjwills: Yes you can create another list and keep adding items to it